# Quota 'CPUS' exceeded

Tags: cf-bosh

I'm following the Cloud Foundry BOSH Fundamentals LiveLessons on Safari. I've deployed BOSH via `bbl` into GCP. I'm using a free trial account which gives me 8 vCPUs. So far I'm using two: one for Director, one for the jumpbox.

I'm trying to deploy nginx with the following command:

```
bosh deploy -d nginx nginx.yml
```

where nginx.yml is

```
---
name: nginx

releases:
- name: nginx
  version: latest

stemcells:
- alias: ubuntu
  os: ubuntu-trusty
  version: latest

instance_groups:
- name: nginx
  azs: [z2]
  instances: 1
  vm_type: sharedcpu
  stemcell: ubuntu
  networks:
  - name: default
  jobs:
  - name: nginx
    release: nginx
    properties:
      nginx_conf: |
        worker_processes  1;
        er ror_log /var/vcap/sys/log/nginx/error.log   info;
        #pid        logs/nginx.pid; # PIDFILE is configured via monit's ctl
        events {
          worker_connections  1024;
        }
        http {
          include /var/vcap/packages/nginx/conf/mime.types;
          default_type  application/octet-stream;
          sendfile        on;
          ssi on;
          keepalive_timeout  65;
          server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
          server {
            server_name _; # invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
            listen 0.0.0.0:80;
            access_log /var/vcap/sys/log/nginx/toto-access.log;
            error_log /var/vcap/sys/log/nginx/toto-error.log;
          }
          root /var/vcap/store/nginx;
          index index.shtml index.html index.htm;
        }
      pre_start: |
        #!/bin/bash -ex
        NGINX_DIR=/var/vcap/store/nginx
        if [ ! -d $NGINX_DIR ]; then
          mkdir -p $NGINX_DIR
          cd $NGINX_DIR
          echo  '<html><title>hello</title><body><h1>Hello <!--#echo var="REMOTE_ADDR" --></h1></body></html>' > index.shtml
        fi

update:
  canaries: 1
  max_in_flight: 1
  serial: false
  canary_watch_time: 1000-60000
  update_watch_time: 1000-60000
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Task 8

Task 8 | 15:47:32 | Preparing deployment: Preparing deployment (00:00:01)
Task 8 | 15:47:33 | Preparing package compilation: Finding packages to compile (00:00:00)
Task 8 | 15:47:33 | Compiling packages: nginx/d6ddf5c4782669341b260a27c53208d32a17b3a5 (00:00:10)
                   L Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::VMCreationFailed' with message 'VM failed to create: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 8.0 in region europe-west3., quotaExceeded' in 'create_vm' CPI method
Task 8 | 15:47:43 | Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::VMCreationFailed' with message 'VM failed to create: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 8.0 in region europe-west3., quotaExceeded' in 'create_vm' CPI method
```

Given I should have 6 vCPUs left, I tried to manually create instances via the web console to see if I would get a similar error. I didn't, I was able to create instances using up the remaining 6 vCPUs. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

[Compilation VMs](https://bosh.io/docs/cloud-config/#compilation) on `bbl` deployed environments take up 8 CPUs by default, which can eat up your quota very fast. The size of the compilation VMs is set by the BOSH cloud config.

The steps to fix this depend on your version of `bbl`. This fix assumes you're using `bbl` 5 or later.

Write a file with the following contents into the `cloud-config` directory of your `bbl` state directory:

```
- type: replace
  path: /compilation/vm_type
  value: n1-highcpu-2
- type: replace
  path: /compilation/workers
  value: 1
```

(You can call this file what you want as long as it does not ovverride an existing file. I would call it something like `compilation-vms.yml`.)

Then run `bbl up` again.

The next time your BOSH director tries to create compilation VMs, it will default to a single 2-CPU VM.